# Swift: Get one line from an NSTextField

Tags: swift, xcode6

G'day,

I have created a simple Swift app with an NSTextField and a button.  The NSTextField is preloaded with some text via the viewDidLoad method.

I want to double click and highlight a single line of text then read that line into a variable when the button is pressed. This should be straight forward but I cannot even get close and I can't find any other questions as simple as this one.

Can someone help?

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ReadTextFields
//
//  Created by Andrew on 5/04/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Andrew. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: NSTextField!


    @IBAction func readTheTextField(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("Read button pushed.")
        // I need some code in here.
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        myTextField.stringValue += "To be or not to be.\n"
        myTextField.stringValue += "That is the question.\n"
        myTextField.stringValue += "Whether tis nobler in the mind,\n"
        myTextField.stringValue += "to suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune."
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the NSScanner class, and specifically the method scanUpToCharactersFromSet. You'd give it a newline character, and have it scan one line at a time into another string.

Comment: Thanks Duncan.  I've used NSScanners in the past.  Great tools.  I would still have the problem of locating the string of interest.  There are some selection tools in the NSTextField class description but I can't make them work. Ta.

Comment: I missed that part of your question. UITtexfield should let you get the range of the current selection. (Not at my Mac right now.)